# SubString of value with several 0s

Tags: sql-server, substring

The data in the table looks like this

```
ID  Value
1   5006049
2   5006050
```

How do I select a substring so that I get

```
R6049
R6050
```

Keeping in mind that the values are sequential starting from

```
5000001 = R1
```

to

```
5999999 = R999999
```

Comment: Yes its an integer column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just substract

```
SELECT 'R' +  CAST(VALUE - 5000000 as VARCHAR(6))
FROM table
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e889f/4)

Comment: Beautiful, I never thought of subtracting. Good job

Comment: CAST or CONVERT is needed to concatenate VARCHAR with non VARCHAR value, yes

Answer (score 0):

I think as easily as this:

```
Select 'R'+Substring(convert(VARCHAR(7), Value), 4,7)
```

Which will give R0001 (do you want the zeros?)

If you don't want the zeros / only looking to remove the top digit:

```
Select 'R'+ convert(VARCHAR(6),Value - 5000000)
```